# Customize Peoplecode App Designer text editor

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

I'm writing a lot of peoplecode in Oracle's Peoplesoft Application Designer 8.53

as far as IDE's go its pretty rudimentary but i'd like to be able to apply a custom Highlighting Scheme or customize the automatic white space manipulation that happens on save.

i found a few registry keys that allowed some customization but is anyone aware of a more complete list of possible registry modifications to customize the app designer text editor?

e.g. the examples i have found so far include

```
"PeoplecodeText"="Text,0,16777215,1,1"
"PeoplecodeTextSelection"="Text Selection,0,65280,0,0"
"PeoplecodeNumber"="Number,16512,16777215,0,1"
"PeoplecodeOperator"="Operator,32896,16777215,0,1"
"PeoplecodeComment"="Comment,10789024,16777215,0,1"
"PeoplecodeQuotedString"="QuotedString,255,16777215,0,1"
"PeoplecodeKeyword"="Keyword,16744448,16777215,0,1"
"PeoplecodeClassDefn"="ClassDefn,8421376,16777215,0,1"
"PeoplecodeBuiltin"="Builtin,8388736,16777215,0,1"
```